# line passing through a point and extending

Tags: tikz-pgf

What if I only want to extend the line 1cm in one direction but not the other?
I found this on another post here from a year ago.

[image: current]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
     extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
     extended line/.default=1cm]

     \node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
     \node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};
     \node [dot=P] at (1.9,-1.6) {};

     \draw [extended line=0.5cm] (A) -- (B);
     \draw [extended line] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) -- (P);

     \fill [red] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) circle [radius=2pt];

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image]

Your figure extends on both ends since `extended line` style has `shorten <=-#1`. If you remove that, then the line will not be extended on the other end. But I suggest that you  add another style.

```
one end extended/.style={shorten >=-#1},
one end extended/.default=1cm,
```

in your options.

Here is the complete code and usage.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[preview,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
 extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
 extended line/.default=1cm,
 one end extended/.style={shorten >=-#1},
 one end extended/.default=1cm,
 ]

 \node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
 \node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};
 \node [dot=P] at (1.9,-1.6) {};

\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (A) -- (B);
\coordinate (P') at ($(A)!(P)!(B)$);
\draw [one end extended] (P') -- (P);

\fill [red] (P') circle [radius=2pt];

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

### Edit

I added `P'` as name of the coordinate `($(A)!(P)!(B)$)` as suggested in comment to speed up compilation time.

Comment: Saving the projected point as a named node might speed up the compilation a bit. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector Done. I haven't timed this. But I wasn't able to see a noticeable difference in compilation time. `:)`

Answer (score 13):

This is possible with `tkz-euclide` or `tkz-base` but here a solution with only `tikz`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
  add/.style args={#1 and #2}{to path={%
 ($(\tikztostart)!-#1!(\tikztotarget)$)--($(\tikztotarget)!-#2!(\tikztostart)$)%
  \tikztonodes}}
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,name=#1}]

 \node [dot=A,label={below:$A$}] at (0,0) {};
 \node [dot=B,label={below:$B$}] at (3,1) {};
 \node [dot=P,label={right:$P$}] at (1.9,-1.6) {};

\draw [add=.5 and .5] (A) to (B);
\coordinate (P') at ($(A)!(P)!(B)$);
\draw [add=0 and .5] (P') to (P);

\fill [red] (P') circle [radius=2pt];

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In PSTricks, we can use `nodesepA` (only for `A` end), `nodesepB` (only for `B` end), or `nodesep` (for both `A` and `B` ends) to shorten or extend the line ends.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(8,6)
    \pstGeonode(2,3){A}(6,5){B}(6,2){P}
    \pstProjection[PointName=none]{A}{B}{P}
    \psset{nodesep=-1}
    \pstLineAB{A}{B}
    \pstLineAB[nodesepB=0]{P}{P'}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `($ (A) !-1cm! (B) $)` syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (B) at (3, 1);
\coordinate (P) at (1.9, -1.6);

\node at (A) [circle, color = black, fill, inner sep = 1 pt] {};
\node at (B) [circle, color = black, fill, inner sep = 1 pt] {};
\node at (P) [circle, color = black, fill, inner sep = 1 pt] {};
\node at (A) [anchor = south] {A};
\node at (B) [anchor = south] {B};
\node at (P) [anchor = west] {P};

\draw ($ (A) !-1cm! (B) $) -- ($ (B) !-1cm! (A) $);
\draw ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) -- ($(P) !-1cm! ($(A)!(P)!(B)$)$);

\fill [red] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) circle [radius = 2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the outcome:

[image: extension]